# interactive images in HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, interactive

This is my first time post so I'll try and make the question as clear as I can.
I've been working with libraries for manipulating the HTML5 canvas element to create draggable, resizeable images against a background as shown [here](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#canvas-2d-example)

This library uses MIT-licensed libraries for `canvasImg`, `canvasElement` and Yahoo utilities. I can't include hyperlinks to these libraries due to first post status, but they're all included with the example.

I'm trying to achieve something similar, with some modifications. First, all of the above example is done in an `iframe` - I'd like it to be a constant size canvas with relative positioning on my page, and I don't think the `iframe` is necessary for what I'm doing.

Since it's going to be used to help people illustrate math problems, I'm also aiming to have the whole thing appear as a new canvas as many times as there are problems, which are created client-side by pressing a "new problem" button. If that's not enough, I also need the settings for them to not interfere with some other MathDox canvases on the same page.

Here's my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[
    $(init);
    probNum = 1;//global var for problem printing
    //CANVAS STUFF
    canvas = [];
    img = [];

    //MATHDOX OPTIONS
    //Define mathdox options
    if (org) {
      alert("org already defined, could not set options");
    } else {
      var org = { mathdox: { formulaeditor: { options: {
        dragPalette:true, 
        paletteShow: "none", 
        useBar:true
      }}}};
    }

    function init(){

        //PROBLEM ADDING
        $("#add_problem").click(addProblem);
        addProblem();

        //TOPIC SELECTION
        //load list from database
        $("#topic0").load("<?=base_url()?>ajax/load_topic_list", {"parent_topic":0});
        //when new topic is selected make a new list
        $("#topic0").change(nextList);
        //if no topic is selected, prevent submit
        $("form").submit( function() {
            if ($("#topic").val() == '-1') 
            {
                $('#error').html("You must select a valid topic");
                return false;
            }
        });


    }//end init

    function addProblem()
    {
        //write everything, but of course without any values
        $('#output').append("<br /><h4>Problem Number " + probNum + "</h4>");
        $('#output').append("<canvas id='canvas"+probNum+"'></canvas>")
        $('#output').append("<textarea class='mathdoxformula' id='formula"+probNum+"' rows='10' cols='80'></textarea><br />\n");
        $('#output').append("<textarea id='txt"+probNum+"'></textarea>\n");
        $("#num_probs").val(probNum);
        //Make a new canvas
        canvas[probNum] = new Canvas.Element();
        canvas[probNum].init(('canvas'+probNum), { width: 400, height: 400});
        img[img.length] = new Canvas.Img('img1', {});
        img[img.length] = new Canvas.Img('img2', {});
        img[img.length] = new Canvas.Img('img3', {});
        canvas[probNum].addImage(img[0]);
        canvas[probNum].addImage(img[1]);
        canvas[probNum].addImage(img[2]);
        canvas[probNum].setCanvasBackground(img[2]);
        //make new formula box
        if (!org) 
        {
            alert("no org");
        }
        org.mathdox.formulaeditor.FormulaEditor.updateByTextAreas();
        //increment problem
        probNum++;
    }

    //More javascript to make the problem selector. I should really start organizing this stuff
    var numSelects = 1;

    function nextList() {
        //define default values for current id, parent and next index
        var topicID = $(this).val();
        var parIndex = $('li').index($(this).parent());
        var nextIndex = $('li').index($(this).parent())+1;
        //when selecting a new topic, destroy all old subselections
        $("#topic_list").children().slice(nextIndex).remove();
        //set new topic id
        $("#topic").val(topicID);
        //if it didn't go to zero, append a new topic
        if (topicID != "-1")
        {
            $('#topic_list').append("<li><select id='topic"+nextIndex+"'></select></li>");
            $('#topic'+nextIndex).load("<?=base_url()?>ajax/load_topic_list", {"parent_topic":topicID});
            $('#topic'+nextIndex).change($.proxy(nextList, $('#topic'+nextIndex)));
        }
    }

    //]]>
    </script>

    <img id="img1" class="canvas-img" src="<?=base_url()?>images/canvas/7.jpg" /> 
    <img id="img2" class="canvas-img" src="<?=base_url()?>images/canvas/8.jpg" /> 
    <img id="img3" class="canvas-img" src="<?=base_url()?>images/canvas/9.jpg" />

    <!--Button to replicate and form closing-->
    <div class="container">
        <button id="add_problem" type="button">Add another problem</button>
    </div>

//and more stuff
```

The topic selection thing isn't what I'm working on, I just included it for completeness.

Now, some of the problems I'm having might be related to style - for one thing the canvas's don't stack properly, instead just getting lined up in a row, and the images do insert but don't drag or resize. I'm having trouble finding beginner-friendly documentation, so if this is actually a very simple problem that I'm not researching properly, please let me know & sorry for the trouble.

Eventually I'd like to have the images inserted by button, but right now I'd be happy if I could just get the canvas to work correctly like it was in the example, but reproduceable with my `addProblem()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered my own question: the yahoo library is a bad choice. I've started using [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) and have found it to be a lot more flexible, with the added bonus that it doesn't need any style editing either.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the example you found is using the Yahoo YUI library. This doesn't mean that it's not good but I can't tel if you do something wrong because I don't use this library.
First, verify that you have included the files of the library like in the example.

Then try to look at the Javascript console for errors in your code. You can display the console (depending on your browser) by pressing CTRL+ALT+I (or CMD+ALT+I on mac). If you find it, you will probably see some errors when you try to drag/resize your images.

For the "multiple canvas at the same time" part, your code looks good for that I think.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried to avoid using the yahoo library as much as I could in my main page code, since I'm really not used to it either, and would be much more comfortable with jquery. My debugging isn't giving me as many errors as just streight up appearance, which indicates style problems to me.